# Explanation of Heat formed by friction

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, friction

Assume you are holding a infiniteley long iron plate(taken metal because its good conductor of heat)in your hand

You start moving your hand with constant velocity on the iron plate then in plate frame of reference or ground frame (ground here refers toy your eye frame both are inertial frame and are at rest in respect to each other) there you will see the kinetic energy is being tranffered from your hand to the plate making it hot and it does gain heat energy from your hand

If you keep doing without removing your hand then your hand will become hot as your hand is moving with constant velocity it can be explained using hand frame of reference by simply saying that the kinetic energy is transferred from iron plate to hand

My question is  How can this phenomenon be explained from ground or plate frame of reference as all should agree on the observations or the event occurred irrespective of their fame of reference

CORRECT ME IF I AM WRONG

Comment: I don't understand about kinetic energy being transferred, because you've said that velocities don't change, so kinetic energies (KEs) don't change. For example, in plate's frame of reference your hand's KE doesn't change, so no KE is transferred from it to the plate.

Comment: What would happen if the body start deaccelerating

Comment: ['decelerating' is the word.] It would be a different situation from the one in your original question, and perhaps a new question is needed. I'd wait and see if you get any answers to the question as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

If your hand is moving at constant velocity on the plate its kinetic energy is constant so there is no transfer of kinetic energy from your hand to the plate. The reason your hand is moving at constant velocity is that the force you apply to your hand parallel to the surface of the plate is equal and opposite to the kinetic friction force between the hand and the plate, for a net force of zero.

But since you are applying a force to your hand over a distance you are doing positive work transferring energy to your hand. The opposing kinetic friction force between your hand and the plate is simultaneously doing negative work of an equal magnitude taking that energy away from your hand. The work is negative because the friction force is opposite to the direction of motion of the hand. Negative work on an object (in this case your hand) removes energy from the object. In this case negative friction work dissipates the energy you gave to your hand as heat at the rubbing surfaces.

At the molecular level, the rubbing action between the hand and plate increases molecular motion at the contacting surfaces. The increased molecular motion causes an increase in temperature at the contacting surfaces of both the hand and plate above the initial temperatures beneath the surfaces of the hand and plate. Because of the temperature difference heat transfers from the surfaces of the hand and plate to their interiors.

For the hand that means there is heat transfer from the epidermis to the dermis below it where the nerves that sense heat and cold are located. Thus the reason the hand feels warm as a result of rubbing. It is a case of increasing the temperature of something as a result of friction work.

I'm not sure I understand the significance of your references to the "plate frame" and "eye frame", as it seems to me they are not only both inertial, but identical as well (the velocity of the hand is the same in both frames).

The hand frame and the plate frames are also inertial, but are different. That's because in the plate frame it is the hand that is moving at constant velocity, whereas in the hand frame it is the plate that is moving at constant velocity. The friction work and the resulting heating is however, the same for both frames .

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can this phenomenon be explained from ground or plate frame of reference because your hand in ground frame is having kinetic energy which is being transferred from the body to the plate and due to that transformation the molecules in plate are gaining energy causing their overall kinetic energy to increase thereby increasing their temperature and hence if energy is transferred from hand to plate then how hand can gain energy and become hot

Comment: Have you taken any course in physics?

Comment: yes high school level

Comment: @ShubhankarMishra It's hard to follow your long sentence. I’ll try to break it down.

Comment: “How can this phenomenon be explained from ground or plate frame of reference”. The friction heating phenomenon between the hand and the plate is the result of the RELATIVE MOTION of the two objects.  Relative motion is the same in all inertial reference frames. The same friction heating is observed from all inertial reference frames. You’ve got to get reference frames out of your head.

Comment: because your hand in ground frame is having kinetic energy (KE) which is being transferred from the body to the plate”. As I’ve already told you KE is not being transferred from the hand to the plate. If it was, the kinetic energy of you hand would be decreasing, which it is not.  The energy source for the friction heating is the  energy transferred to the hand by work done by the body , not the kinetic energy of the hand.

Comment: Now if you were say pushing a box along the plate and released it, the box would slow down and eventually stop due to the friction force. Then you could say kinetic energy is transferred from the hand.

Comment: “…due to that transformation the molecules in plate are gaining energy causing their overall kinetic energy to increase thereby increasing their temperature and hence if energy is transferred from hand to plate then how hand can gain energy and become hot”.

Comment: The negative work done by friction is SIMULTANEOUSLY increasing molecular kinetic energy of both the surface of the hand and surface of the plate. The temperatures of BOTH are simultaneously and individually increased due to the friction work. After that there is heat transfer to the interiors of the hand and plate, and between the plate due to any temperature difference.